# Software to create ebooks with markdown

Tags: pdf, markdown, ebooks, epub, mobi

I'm currently looking for a way on macOS to create an ebook (PDF, ePub, and Mobi) using markdown syntax, but I can't find a good app/service for that. I tried using the template feature in iA Writer, but it does not support adding a cover image on the first page of the generated PDF. This app also doesn't support exporting to ePub or Mobi formats.

I'm actually a developer, and I can create an app/script that lets me convert markdown to an ebook with any formatting/styling I want, but I'm trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel. So please let me know if you know any good software to accomplish that, otherwise I'll do it myself (and share it with you if you're interested).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), etc. So I've changed the title of your question. Could you please [edit] it again and add some more details – e.g. on what OS the software should run, or for what programming language the libraries should be. Also include your price margin.

Answer (score 2):

Try [pandoc](https://pandoc.org). If you want something that incorporates editing and publishing, check out [LeanPub](https://leanpub.com/).

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [texts](http://www.texts.io/features/)
a markdown editor that uses [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) for document conversion and latex for pdf.

as for Mobi, export a Epub or html then  use [kindlegen](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000765211) from Amazon to make the Mobi

hope this helps

[prince](https://www.princexml.com/download/) is another option for html => pdf

Answer (score 0):

The R- and Rstudio-communities are working hard to create a publishing system, [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/), primarily based on the R programming language. That's because the major developers who are doing this are employees of RStudio, an IDE for R. I think the developers trying to make the product more language-agnostic, but this is more a long-term project.

"bookdown" is is an "extension" for RStudio. It is also a suite of R packages, and is also based on [*pandoc*](https://pandoc.org/).

For an introduction with e-books in mind, read this: [How to self publish a book: customizing Bookdown](https://blog.datascienceheroes.com/how-to-self-publish-a-book-customizing-bookdown/)

Recently there was also a competition, now finished, for creating the best book with Bookdown. Some examples, scroll down [the blogpost](https://community.rstudio.com/t/announcing-winners-of-the-1st-bookdown-contest/16394).